# Suction hose or regular PVC hose?

Tags: pumps, vacuum-pumps, hydrodynamics, plumbing

I had a liquid filling machine to which on the suction side I had applied regular PVC hose

[image: image description]

Some time back I had a problem that after some use the hose was beginning to breathe air. How do I know it was breathing air? I know it was breathing air because when completely submerged in the liquid to be filled the filling was optimal, when not completely submerged it filling was short.

Then came someone's suggestion that I should use a suction hose. I checked it and apparently a suction hose is the same pvc but with some spiral wire which make it fit for -ve pressure, i.e, it is unlikely to collapse. My question, would that suffice? My earlier PVC hose only collapsed under its own weight and at bends when the ambient temperature was hot

Comment: either thaqt suction hose you mentioned or some steel flexible hose.

Comment: suction hose is made for suction.  It might be your other hose was collapsing and then the higher vacuum made the connection to the pump leak.  Or you just thought it was sucking air when the problem was no flow through the collapsed tube.

Comment: @TigerGuy unlikely, there are sensors involved which measure flow.

Comment: Alright, will try suction pvc hose first. Steel flexible hoses might not be suitable as I think they use SS 202 or something (I'm even tempted to think MS), but I have seen it rust and this thing needs to be submerged. Bard suggested rubber or silicone, but rubber tends to get bad over time and silicone is just too expensive plus perhaps unsuitable for -ve pressures.